# Delete a string out of a linked list of strings

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I am working on a word processor where it is requested to be able to delete a word out of a list of words.

Basically, the user enters words (thus, strings of characters) which are then stored in a linked list (here dico, thanks to the structure dictionary which represents all the words that the user has entered).

I am unfortunately stuck : it seems like the code I wrote only ever deletes the second character, whereas I would like it to be able to delete the word requested by the user (here : str).

For instance, if the user had previously entered : "hello world" and they would now like to delete the world "world", the dico should now be "hello".

```
typedef struct dll {
    char data;
    int count;      //not needed here
    struct dll* next;
} dll;  //linked list of each character : dll represents one word

typedef struct dictionary {
    dll * data;
    struct dictionary* next;
    struct dictionary* prev;
} dictionary;  //linked list of all the words

dll* entry(){
    char data = getc(stdin);
    if (data != '\n'){
        dll* curr = create_dico(data);
        curr->next=entry();
        return curr;
    }
    return NULL;
}


void suppression(dictionary** dico) {
    printf("Please enter what you wish to remove out of the list: \n");
    dictionary *str = malloc(sizeof(dictionary));
    str->data = entry();
    str->next = NULL;

    dictionary* temp = *dico;

    if (str->data == NULL){
        *dico = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    while (temp != NULL && temp->data->data == str->data->data) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    dictionary *next = temp->next->next;
    free(temp->next);
    temp->next = next;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please note that [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) return an `int` value. This is so you could check for `EOF` which indicate end-of-file or an error. Which you really should check for as well.

Comment: you need two loops, one to loop over `dictionary` and other to loop over `word in dictionary`.

Comment: Recommendation: Rather create the entry within a loop than recursively (`while(data != \n) { ... }`). Hint: you'll need two pointers then, one to the head, one to the tail of the list currently being created.

Answer (score 1):

Your deletion function doesn't reflect the data structures you are using: linked lists of linked lists!

The very first thing you need to do is detect where the *word* is located, you need to compare the two linked lists for that purpose:

```
// notice: pointer to dll, not dictionary!
dll* str = entry();

dictionary* temp = *dico;
while(temp)
{
    dll* s = str; // you yet need original str for deletion!
    dll* word = temp->data;
    while(word && s && word->data == s->data)
    {
        word = word->next;
        s = s->next;
    }
    // OK, now we need to know if we reached the ends of BOTH word and s
    // -> in that case, both are equal!
    if(!word && !s)
        break;
}
```

So we iterated over the words list now. If we found the string inside, we stopped prematurely, otherwise we reached the null-element at the very end. So:

```
if(temp)
{
    // we didn't reach end of the words' list -> we found an equal element

    // at first, we'd remove the current word from the linked simply by
    // re-linking predecessor and successor nodes
    // the nice thing about is that you created a doubly linked list
    // so we have both of them available from current node, so:

    if(temp->prev)
        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
    else
        // special case: we are deleting the head node!
        *dico = temp->next;

    if(temp->next)
        temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
    // no else needed, as we haven't a dedicated tail node

    // now we need to delete the word's characters!
    dll* word = temp->data;
    while(word)
    {
        dll* next = word->next;
        free(word);
        word = next;
    }

    // now we yet need to delete the word node itself!
    free(temp);
}
```

Fine so far, the list is adjusted. We created a temporary reference string, though, which itself needs to be freed again as well:

```
while(str)
    // well, just the same as when deleting the word...
```

As you do the same thing twice, you might create a common function for...

Be aware that above is untested code, no guarantee that it is bug-free. But it should suffice to show where you have to keep an eye on... Be aware, too, that this answer is based on quite a few *assumptions*, mainly the lists having been created correctly before, as you didn't provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).